# Spring STS: Moving classes to other folders causes not found error when running url

Tags: java, spring

When I place ALL my classes, that is Controllers, Models, etc under the MAIN umbrella folder, my app works as expected:

```
src\main\java
|- myapp package
   |-all classes here
```

But if I try to place classes under appropriate folders to keep a cleaner hierarchy, then the app will throw an object not found error. For example:

```
src\main\java
|- myapp package
   |-myapp.java
|- controller package
   |- controllerclass.java
|- model package
   |- modelclass.java
```

This causes object not found when url invoked even though the app builds.

I'm new to Spring, so not sure if I missed something in the setup somewhere. Any advice appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using spring boot. In order to make your classes eligible for auto wire candidate, they should be in same package or you have to specify the packages through **@ComponentScan** annotation in your MyApp class

```
@ComponentScan({"controller", "model"})
public class MyApp {
  ...
}
```